# Error during arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ cross compile. Shared library file not recognized

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a c++ code for a 64-bit architecture arm device using the ARM cross compiler toolchain from here https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain .

My compile command is

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc examples/neon_cartoon_effect.cpp utils/Utils.cpp -I. -Iinclude -std=c++11 -mfpu=neon -L/home/deeptihegde/ComputeLibrary/build  -larm_compute -o build/neon_cartoon_effect
```

I get the below error

```
/home/deeptihegde/ComputeLibrary/build/libarm_compute.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

.
Is this a compiler issue? Did I link it incorrectly?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you run `file /home/deeptihegde/ComputeLibrary/build/libarm_compute.so` what does it say? Is the library also cross-compiled?

Comment: it gives this:

/home/deeptihegde/ComputeLibrary/build/libarm_compute.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=779ad964649f926da1ee4d2d834c37d8259f85af, not stripped

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , will changing the compiler to a 64-bit arm compiler work?

Comment: Considering that you target a 64-bit platform and the library was built for a 64-bit target, then yes that would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Alright, i compiled using the g++-aarch64-linux-gnu toolchain. Now, I am getting an error for the -mpfu=neon tag.  When I compile without it, all the places  use NEON throw an error.  Any other suggested compiler? Does it matter if I build the compiler from source or not?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , would clang work better? I am not able to solve those neon errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are trying to link 32bit application(neon_cartoon_effect) with 64bit Library (libarm_compute.so).